# Rails Get Data from Parent Data and Show in Nested View as a Page Tittle (heading)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested, view

I'm trying to get the Members first and last name to show up as a title on all the nested address views. So far I came up with this (just for the index), this is probably not the "rails way" but it was the only way I figured it out for now.

```
def index
    @membercontact = Backend::Membercontact.find(params[:membercontact_id])
    membercontact = Backend::Membercontact.find(params[:membercontact_id])
    @memberaddresses = membercontact.memberaddresses.order('mafullname ASC')
end
```

The line I'm really concentrating on is:

```
<h2>Private Address Information - <%= @membercontact.mcfirstname + ' ' + @membercontact.mclastname %></h2>
```

Each view has this at the top (I know not very DRY) but just for now to learn. But that's how the above line looks like within the view.

```
<!-- Bread Crumbs -->
<div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
    <h2>Private Address Information - <%= @membercontact.mcfirstname + ' ' + @membercontact.mclastname %></h2>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li> 
                <a>Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <%= link_to main_app.backend_membercontacts_path, class: "nav-link" do %>
                    Members List
                <% end %>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
        <%= link_to main_app.backend_membercontact_memberaddresses_path, class: "nav-link" do %>
                    Private Address List
                <% end %>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Would I have to add the line below to every controller action? Or is there a better way I can go about this.

```
@membercontact = Backend::Membercontact.find(params[:membercontact_id])
```

I also have seen a similar questions but I think you had to call the data in between the for each

```
<% @memberaddresses.each do |memberaddress| %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is for `@membercontact` to be available in every action of every controller, you can have it defined in a method in application_controller.rb and have that method run before every action by using the [before_action](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-before_action) directive.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have to be calling the @membercontact line in each controller:

```
@membercontact = Backend::Membercontact.find(params[:membercontact_id])
```

Unless the `membercontact_id` will always be the same for a particular session (eg: if the `membercontact_id` will be the `current_user.id`) - Is this the case?

However, you may have an instance method in your `Backend::Membercontact` class, that will be returning the `full name` as follow:

```
def full_name
  mcfirstname + " " + mclastname
end
```

and then call the `full_name` method on your `@membercontact` from inside the view.

Also, if all your views will be having the same header: `Private Address Information...`, you might as well be returning that from inside the model as well, maybe get something like:

```
def page_title
  "Private Address Information - " + mcfirstname + " " + mclastname
end
```

The last one is if the `member` will be constant across all controllers(for example if the member is the current user), then you can have a service class to return:

```
def self.page_title
  "Private Address Information - " + current_user.mcfirstname + " " + current_user.mclastname
end
```

and then from each controller, `@page_title = MyServiceClass.page_title` and just be calling the following from inside your view:

```
<h2><%= @page_title %></h2>
```

Hope this helps well...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like your solution, but in this case member is not tied to a session or anything.